# scrollview size doesn't take into account nested child sizes that overflow their parent

Tags: react-native

I am working on UI in which View is placed in horizontal scrollbar and view has to have it's width specified so that it's children would render properly - however when I specify size for the View, scroll view thinks that is the size that it should work against - doesn't allow scrolling in content from nested View children that overflow render outside View's specified width.

Setting 'width' on contentContainerStyle has the same effect.

I am guessing this is the way react native works but wondering if there is a way to make this works without resorting to javascript run on layout - in web "overflow: auto" is able to recognize size of the content correctly regardless of how width property is configured on it's child elements.

Comment: Setting the width shouldn't cause such an issue, please provide a code sample.

Comment: <View style={{ width: 300, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'gray' }}>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} contentContainerStyle={{ width: 200 }}>
        <View style={{ width: 200, overflow: 'visible' }}>
          <View style={{ width: 3000, height: 100, backgroundColor: 'lightgray' }}>
            <Text>
              abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    </View>

Comment: that is the simplest repro - both width: 200 in contentContainerStyle and width: 200 in top view under scrollbar need to be removed for scrolling to work

Comment: If child component layout is dependent on parent layout. You must assign some width/height to parent. Otherwise conflict occurs and things do not work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your implementation is that you are setting a custom width to the contentContainerStyle, when you set any of its dimensions manually it breaks the scroll functionality. Instead set the width of each item and let ScrollView take care of listing them. Below is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, ScrollView, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function () {
  const myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  function renderBox({value}) {
    return (
      <View
        key={value}
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: 10,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <ScrollView
        horizontal
        contentContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        {myList.map(value => renderBox({value}))}
      </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

A better implementation altogether is probably using FlatList:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';

export default function () {
  const myList = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

  function renderBox({item: value}) {
    return (
      <View
        key={value}
        style={{
          marginHorizontal: 10,
          width: 100,
          height: 50,
          backgroundColor: 'blue',
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>{value}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      }}>
      <FlatList
        contentContainerStyle={{
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}
        horizontal
        data={myList}
        renderItem={renderBox}
        keyExtractor={value => value}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Notice in the ScrollView solution I dont put a list wrapper inside the ScrollView because that defeats the purpose of having a scrollable component. ScrollView expects a list of items to scroll through, dont give it a wrapper with items inside the wrapper.

Comment: this doesn't solve my problem - example I've listed is just a minimal repro of the issue I have, sorry about that - situation is that there is an element that is in scroll view and it has children out of which some may be flexible (not in my control) - flexible children should take remaining space if there is some, or flex when there is no space, for this to work width of the view that contains them (or contentContainerStyle) needs to be set to referent value - which in turn breaks the scrolling.

Comment: ScrollView will take the width of its parent, when I used flex: 1 for example it covered the whole page. So try manipulating the ScrollView parent width and in the ScrollView have the items with dynamic width. Their width can either be a flex value or a static number.